# NativeScript iPhone X place content in safe area

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, iphone-x

is it possible to place content, in my case a button, inside the (bottom) place area on iPhoneX?

This is what it looks right now.

[image]

For better understanding here is my HTML.
As I understand Apple it is not possible to insert any content into the safe areas except scroll views.

### HTML

```
<FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column"
               justifyContent="space-between"
               alignContent="center"
               alignItems="center"
               class="transparentBackground"
               height="100%">
    <FlexboxLayout justifyContent="flex-end"
                   alignItems="center"
                   flexDirection="row"
                   class="action-bar">
        <Label *ngIf="isAdmin"
               text="&#xf086;"
               class="font-awesome action-bar-item"
               (tap)="onAdminPush()"></Label>
        <Label text="&#xf039;"
               class="font-awesome action-bar-item"
               (tap)="onAppointments()"></Label>
    </FlexboxLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout width="350"
                    height="350"
                    (tap)="onStartAppointment()">
        <Image stretch="aspectFill"
               borderColor="gray"
               borderWidth="1"
               borderRadius="200"
               width="350"
               height="350"
               src="~/Assets/Imgs/terminanfrage.png"></Image>
        <FlexboxLayout alignItems="center"
                       justifyContent="center"
                       width="100%"
                       height="100%"
                       style="color:black;">
            <Label text="Terminanfrage"
                   class="label--appointment font-title-rrm"></Label>
        </FlexboxLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <Button class="btn btn-primary call_button font-title-rrm"      
            id="button"
            text="Im Büro anrufen"
            (tap)="onCallOffice()"></Button>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your HTML looks like, but if you have a GridLayout which takes up the entire page, you can set `verticalAlignment="bottom"` on one of its children.

EDIT: I made a comment with this, but the content didn't get formatted the way I had hoped. To test whether or not it's possible to put something in the safe zone, try doing this:

```
<GridLayout rows="* 50" height="100%" width="100%" backgroundColor="blue">
    <Button row="1" text="test" backgroundColor="red" verticalAlignment="bottom"></Button>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with my HTML. verticalAlignment="bottom" seems not to work if I place it on the button.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with `FlexboxLayout`, but your problem might stem from `justifyContent="space-between"`. If you want to experiment with whether or not putting content in the safe zone is possible, try something like this:

    <GridLayout rows="* 50" height="100%" width="100%" backgroundColor="blue">
            <Button row="1" text="test" backgroundColor="red" verticalAlignment="bottom"></Button>
    </GridLayout>